# Facebook Request get errorcode :-1, can not get albums

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

I use the lastest SDK version 4.9.0 for android.
I want to get my albums and use the code below:

```
GetUserAlbumsRequestCallback getUserAlbumsRequestCallback = new GetUserAlbumsRequestCallback();
            GraphRequest requestUserAlbumsRequest = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),                   "me",null,null,getUserAlbumsRequestCallback);

        Bundle parameters_requestUserAlbumsRequest = new Bundle();
                        parameters_requestUserAlbumsRequest.putString("fields", "albums.limit(500){id,name,cover_photo,count,photos.limit(500){id,name,picture,source,width,height,images}}");
                        parameters_requestUserAlbumsRequest.putString("locale", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
                        requestUserAlbumsRequest.setParameters(parameters_requestUserAlbumsRequest);

        GraphRequestBatch batch = new GraphRequestBatch(requestUserAlbumsRequest);
     batch.addCallback(new GraphRequestBatch.Callback() {
    ........
    }
    batch.executeAsync();
```

and then in the GetUserAlbumsRequestCallback  class,

```
public class GetUserAlbumsRequestCallback implements GraphRequest.Callback {
     public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
     // the response is not excepted
     }

}
```

below is the response:

> {Response: responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus:
>   -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: could not construct request body}}

but sometimes I can get the right data,when i finish the activity with back key,and then re-enter the activity with facebook,it sometimes shows incorrect.

I don't know what happend ,and can you help me ?
I use the Facebook sdk for android version 4.9.0

Comment: are you sure there is locale parameter ? have you tried without it ?

Comment: yes.And i tried without it ,sometimes the error still appear